# Expected 2 got 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, graphics, computer-vision

Hi I was wondering how can I fix this issue when it expects to receive two but it gets nothing? Also I have been trying to run the code called this github but I have been getting numerous errors. The code can be seen https://github.com/CSAILVision/IBD

I have tried deleting the underline character and the edit the code so it doesn't have any red lines preventing it from running

```
import os
import settings
from loader.model_loader import loadmodel
from util.feature_operation import FeatureOperator
from util.clean import clean
from util.feature_decoder import SingleSigmoidFeatureClassifier
from util.image_operation import *
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

from imageio import imread


from visualize.plot import random_color
from torch.autograd import Variable as V
import torch


model = loadmodel()
fo = FeatureOperator()

features, _ = fo.feature_extraction(0)

for layer_id, layer in enumerate(settings.FEATURE_NAMES):
    feat_clf = SingleSigmoidFeatureClassifier(feature=features[layer_id], layer=layer, fo=fo)
    feat_clf.load_snapshot(14, unbiased=True)

data_loader.py:156: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  result[list(np.indices(arr.shape)) + [arr]] = 1
loading features layer4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    features, _ = fo.feature_extraction(0)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Comment: You got an error, not 0. What are we supposed to be helping with here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the code and the error message:

```
features, _ = fo.feature_extraction(0)
...
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

You tried to assign two values, but `feature_extraction` doesn't return any at all.
Re-visit the documentation and usage notes?

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much!